# CORS request did not succeed

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a problem when I want to create an authentication system using VueJs as the frontend (`http://localhost:8080/#/login`) and Laravel 5.6 as the backend. When I try to submit login form using the api login url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login`, I get the error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
>   reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Could anyone here help me to solve my problem?

**NOTE :** I have to install [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) before

Answer (score 21):

This is an old question, but I'll reply nonetheless.

For me this error was caused by a self-signed certificate. If you open developer tools, select the network tab, click the call that failed CORS you can see the security tab. Click it to open it. If a cert is giving you problems the text "An error occurred:    SEC_ERROR_INADEQUATE_KEY_USAGE" should be visible.

To resolve this just go to the URL that gave you the CORS error, and accept the cert manually.

Answer (score 3):

Cross Origin Resource Sharing is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to allow the web application running on one origin (client) have permission to access selected resources from a server at a different origin.

Basically, your Vue app (http://localhost:8080) needs to be allowed access to your Laravel endpoint (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login) This is to prevent me from hitting your Laravel endpoint from my malicious website and acting like an authenticated user.

Based on the [docs](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors#configuration), you need to add `'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],` but that means you're opening up your backend to all requests. That's fine if it's a public API but in this context it doesn't sound like you want that. Instead, in this case it would be `'allowedOrigins' => ['localhost:8080'],` so that your Vue app can consume your Laravel server.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for all the requests. In general in your code you should make calls to the server by just appending the URI to the current host, without re-adding the host and port in the URI string. If you load your page from a given host, for example `127.0.0.1` and then try to make an AJAX request to another host, for example `www.host.com`, the request gets blocked to prevent [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are running this in dev mode via webpack currently?  If that is correct and your workflow is that you are going to build the Vue application and have it co-reside with your Laravel backend then you just need to update `config/index.js` to have a `proxyTable` entry that forwards webpack requests to the correct dev Laravel backend server.

This would look something like this.

```
module.exports = {
  dev: {
    proxyTable: {
      "/": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/login"
    }
  }
}
```

There is additional information available on how this works; https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with this error recently while I was trying to get one of our old websites hosted via Azure (App Services) up and running again.

`Reason: CORS request did not succeed` was the error showing in the browser console, however, it turned that for our case the URL mentioned in the CORS error doesn't exist anymore - its referring to the old `https://******.azurewebsites.net` service url we had (previous hosted in Azure - App Services).

So also check that the URL mentioned in the CORS-error is in fact working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the computer was not displaying the correct date and time. When I try to view the page I would get the "CORS request did not succeed." Once I updated to the correct time and date the page displayed normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the base URL of axios. I didn't notice it was **https://**, not **http://**

file: src\store\index.js

change the

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/api'
```

to

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api'
```

Note: Make sure it's exactly same URL and Port. You can see that in terminal where you start the laravel application (`php artisan serve`).