# Cors enabled on php file, but still getting error

Tags: php, reactjs, cors, axios

I'm building an API, for training purposes. I now have to send a POST request containing information. I'm using React JS and PHP, the problem is that everytime I send a request, the CORS error still shows up on the browser.

My JS file that sends the POST is, I changed the URL, because it's on my personal server:

```
  axios.post('https://myurl/api/book/create.php', {
   data: JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

and on the server side, I have the following

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

With postman the request goes smoothly, but every single time sending through the browser

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://myurl/api/book/create.php. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you allow CORS in backend server. Then, you need send header for axios like following example

```
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.defaults.crossDomain = true;
```

(Or setting it in third paramenter after data)

Comment: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘https://myurl/book/livro/create.php’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’)"

It's enabled on my server.

Comment: @ZephSenpai please allow `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`

Comment: @ZephSenpai you can not use `*` when credentials are send with the request, you _must_ respond with the exact content of the `Origin` request header.

Comment: @misorude can you please explain more?

Comment: @ZephSenpai The remote server needs to respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/` (or whatever your actual origin is), when you make a request that includes credentials.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for all the requests. In general in your code you should make calls to the server by just appending the URI to the current host, without re-adding the host and port in the URI string.

Answer based on: [CORS request did not succeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331029/cors-request-did-not-succeed)

Comment: I'm sending the request from the localhost. The server on the otherhand is online, I'm only using it for the db.